# How can I check wether a point is inside the circumcircle of 3 points?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Is there any easy solution? Or has anybody an example of an implementation?

Thanks, Jonas

Comment: Why not just [calculate the circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcircle.html) and check for inclusion?

Answer (score 12):

Lets call

- a, b, c our three points,
- C the circumcircle of (a, b, c)
- and d an other point.

A fast way to determine if d is in C is to compute this determinant:

```
      | ax-dx, ay-dy, (ax-dx)² + (ay-dy)² |
det = | bx-dx, by-dy, (bx-dx)² + (by-dy)² |
      | cx-dx, cy-dy, (cx-dx)² + (cy-dy)² |
```

if a, b, c are in counter clockwise order then:

- if det equal 0 then d is on C
- if det > 0 then d is inside C
- if det < 0 then d is outside C

here is a javascript function that does just that:

```
function inCircle (ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy) {
    let ax_ = ax-dx;
    let ay_ = ay-dy;
    let bx_ = bx-dx;
    let by_ = by-dy;
    let cx_ = cx-dx;
    let cy_ = cy-dy;
    return (
        (ax_*ax_ + ay_*ay_) * (bx_*cy_-cx_*by_) -
        (bx_*bx_ + by_*by_) * (ax_*cy_-cx_*ay_) +
        (cx_*cx_ + cy_*cy_) * (ax_*by_-bx_*ay_)
    ) > 0;
}
```

You might also need to check if your points are in counter clockwise order:

```
function ccw (ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy) {
    return (bx - ax)*(cy - ay)-(cx - ax)*(by - ay) > 0;
}
```

I didn't place the ccw check inside the inCircle function because you shouldn't check it every time.

This process doesn't take any divisions or square root operation.

You can see the code in action there: https://titouant.github.io/testTriangle/

And the source there: https://github.com/TitouanT/testTriangle

Answer (score 8):

(In case you are interested in a non-obvious/"crazy" kind of solution.)

One equivalent property of Delaunay triangulation is as follows: if you build a circumcircle of any triangle in the triangulation, it is guaranteed not to contain any other vertices of the triangulation.

Another equivalent property of Delaunay triangulation is: it maximizes the minimal triangle angle (i.e. maximizes it among all triangulations on the same set of points).

This suggests an algorithm for your test:

1. Consider triangle `ABC` built on the original 3 points.
2. If the test point `P` lies inside the triangle it is definitely inside the circle
3. If the test point `P` belongs to one of the "corner" regions (see the shaded regions in the picture below), it is definitely outside the circle

[image]

1. Otherwise (let's say `P` lies in region 1) consider two triangulations of quadrilateral `ABCP`: the *original* one contains the original triangle (red diagonal), and the *alternate* one with "flipped" diagonal (blue diagonal)

[image]

1. Determine which one if this triangulations is a Delaunay triangulation by testing [the "flip" condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Visual_Delaunay_definition:_Flipping), e.g. by comparing `α = min(∠1,∠4,∠5,∠8)` vs. `β = min(∠2,∠3,∠6,∠7)`.
2. If the *original* triangulation is a Delaunay triangulation (`α > β`), `P` lies outside the circle. If the *alternate* triangulation is a Delaunay triangulation (`α < β`), `P` lies inside the circle.

Done.

---

(Revisiting this answer after a while.)

This solution might not be as "crazy" as it might appear at the first sight. Note that in order to compare angles at steps 5 and 6 there's no need to calculate the actual angle values. It is sufficient to know their cosines (i.e. there's no need to involve trigonometric functions).

A C++ version of the code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

struct pnt_t
{
  int x, y;

  pnt_t ccw90() const
    { return { -y, x }; }

  double length() const
    { return std::hypot(x, y); }

  pnt_t &operator -=(const pnt_t &rhs)
  {
    x -= rhs.x;
    y -= rhs.y;
    return *this;
  }

  friend pnt_t operator -(const pnt_t &lhs, const pnt_t &rhs)
    { return pnt_t(lhs) -= rhs; }

  friend int operator *(const pnt_t &lhs, const pnt_t &rhs)
    { return lhs.x * rhs.x + lhs.y * rhs.y; }
};

int side(const pnt_t &a, const pnt_t &b, const pnt_t &p)
{
  int cp = (b - a).ccw90() * (p - a);
  return (cp > 0) - (cp < 0);
}

void make_ccw(std::array<pnt_t, 3> &t)
{
  if (side(t[0], t[1], t[2]) < 0)
    std::swap(t[0], t[1]);
}

double ncos(pnt_t a, const pnt_t &o, pnt_t b)
{
  a -= o;
  b -= o;
  return -(a * b) / (a.length() * b.length());
}

bool inside_circle(std::array<pnt_t, 3> t, const pnt_t &p)
{
  make_ccw(t);

  std::array<int, 3> s = 
    { side(t[0], t[1], p), side(t[1], t[2], p), side(t[2], t[0], p) };

  unsigned outside = std::count(std::begin(s), std::end(s), -1);
  if (outside != 1)
    return outside == 0;

  while (s[0] >= 0)
  {
    std::rotate(std::begin(t), std::begin(t) + 1, std::end(t));
    std::rotate(std::begin(s), std::begin(s) + 1, std::end(s));
  }

  double 
    min_org = std::min({
      ncos(t[0], t[1], t[2]), ncos(t[2], t[0], t[1]), 
      ncos(t[1], t[0], p), ncos(p, t[1], t[0]) }),
    min_alt = std::min({
      ncos(t[1], t[2], p), ncos(p, t[2], t[0]), 
      ncos(t[0], p, t[2]), ncos(t[2], p, t[1]) });

  return min_org <= min_alt;
}
```

and a couple of tests with arbitrarily chosen triangles and a large number of random points

[image]
[image]

---

Of course, the whole thing can be easily reformulated without even mentioning Delaunay triangulations. Starting from step 4 this solution is based in the property of the opposite angles of [cyclic quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral), which must sum to 180°.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this, as it answers a question I had, but I'm running into an issue. You mention that your method is based on the flip condition, where the sum of the angles is <= 180 degrees. But in your sample code, you don't use angles, you just calculate the cosines, and rather than sum them you just take the minimum of all angles. How does that work? Certain angles from a cosine are always negative, doesn't that bias the calculation? How does taking the minimum cosine accomplish the same thing as summing the angles, to determine which one is Delaunay?

Comment: @Nairou: In order to compare the angles I use `ncos` function, which strands for "negative cosine", i.e. simply the negation of the actual cosine. It behaves uniformly across the whole `[0, Pi)` range: the larger is the angle - the larger is its `ncos`. (Although in this problem, if I'm not missing anything, we'll only be dealing with acute angles.).

Comment: As for the flip condition, it has multiple *equivalent* formulations. The one at the link (in Wikipedia) is based on summing the angles. I use a different (yet *equivalent*) form of flip condition, which I described in point 5 of my answer: flip to maximize the minimum angle. This version of flip condition does not require summing the angles and does not even require *knowing* the angle values. It only requires one to be able to *compare* the angles. Which is the whole reason I chose *this* form of flip condition.

Comment: If you read a bit more about Delanay triangulation, you'll see that it has many interesting properties, which can actually be shown to follow from one another. These properties can be used to build different (and yet equivalent) flip conditions. Here we are seeing the two most well-known ones.

Answer (score 2):

In [this Math SE post of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/599456/35416) I included an equation which checks if four points are cocircular by computing a 4×4 determinant. By turning that equation into an inequality you can check for insideness.

If you want to know which direction the inequality has to go, conisder the case of a point very far away. In this case, the *x*²+*y*² term will dominate all other terms. So you can simply assume that for the point in question, this term is one while the three others are zero. Then pick the sign of your inequality so this value does *not* satisfy it, since this point is definitely outside but you want to characterize inside.

If numeric precision is an issue, [this page by Prof. Shewchuk](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake/robust.html) describes how to obtain consistent predicates for points expressed using regular double precision floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Given 3 points `(x1,y1)`,`(x2,y2)`,`(x3,y3)` and the point you want to check is inside the circle defined by the above 3 points `(x,y)` you can do something like

```java
/**
 *
 * @param x coordinate of point want to check if inside
 * @param y coordinate of point want to check if inside
 * @param cx center x
 * @param cy center y
 * @param r radius of circle
 * @return whether (x,y) is inside circle
 */
static boolean g(double x,double y,double cx,double cy,double r){
    return Math.sqrt((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy))<r;
}

// check if (x,y) is inside circle defined by (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)
static boolean isInside(double x,double y,double x1,double y1,double x2,double y2,double x3,double y3){
    double m1 = (x1-x2)/(y2-y1);
    double m2 = (x1-x3)/(y3-y1);
    double b1 = ((y1+y2)/2) - m1*(x1+x2)/2;
    double b2 = ((y1+y3)/2) - m2*(x1+x3)/2;
    double xx = (b2-b1)/(m1-m2);
    double yy = m1*xx + b1;
    return g(x,y,xx,yy,Math.sqrt((xx-x1)*(xx-x1)+(yy-y1)*(yy-y1)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // if (0,1) is inside the circle defined by (0,0),(0,2),(1,1)
    System.out.println(isInside(0,1,0,0,0,2,1,1));
}
```

The method for getting an expression for the center of circle from 3 points goes from finding the intersection of the 2 [perpendicular bisectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection#Line_segment_bisector) of 2 line segments, above I chose `(x1,y1)-(x2,y2)` and `(x1,y1)-(x3,y3)`. Since you know a point on each perpendicular bisector, namely `(x1+x2)/2` and `(x1+x3)/2`, and since you also know the slope of each perpendicular bisector, namely `(x1-x2)/(y2-y1)` and `(x1-x3)/(y3-y1)` from the above 2 line segments respectively, you can solve for the (x,y) where they intersect.