# Check Delaunay "flip condition" using only cosines

Tags: trigonometry, delaunay

While searching for methods of determining whether a point is within a circumcircle, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39988628/187949) answer, which used an interesting method of constructing a quadrilateral between the point and triangle, and testing the [flip condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Visual_Delaunay_definition:_Flipping) to see if the new point makes a better Delaunay triangle, and therefore is within the original triangle's circumcircle.

The Delaunay flip condition deals with angles, however, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39988628/187949) I found instead just calculates the cosines of the angles. Rather than checking that the sum of angles is less than or equal to 180°, it takes the minimum of all (negated) cosines, comparing the two results to decide if the point is in the circle.

Here is the code from that answer (copied here for convenience):

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

struct pnt_t
{
  int x, y;

  pnt_t ccw90() const
    { return { -y, x }; }

  double length() const
    { return std::hypot(x, y); }

  pnt_t &operator -=(const pnt_t &rhs)
  {
    x -= rhs.x;
    y -= rhs.y;
    return *this;
  }

  friend pnt_t operator -(const pnt_t &lhs, const pnt_t &rhs)
    { return pnt_t(lhs) -= rhs; }

  friend int operator *(const pnt_t &lhs, const pnt_t &rhs)
    { return lhs.x * rhs.x + lhs.y * rhs.y; }
};

int side(const pnt_t &a, const pnt_t &b, const pnt_t &p)
{
  int cp = (b - a).ccw90() * (p - a);
  return (cp > 0) - (cp < 0);
}

void make_ccw(std::array<pnt_t, 3> &t)
{
  if (side(t[0], t[1], t[2]) < 0)
    std::swap(t[0], t[1]);
}

double ncos(pnt_t a, const pnt_t &o, pnt_t b)
{
  a -= o;
  b -= o;
  return -(a * b) / (a.length() * b.length());
}

bool inside_circle(std::array<pnt_t, 3> t, const pnt_t &p)
{
  make_ccw(t);

  std::array<int, 3> s = 
    { side(t[0], t[1], p), side(t[1], t[2], p), side(t[2], t[0], p) };

  unsigned outside = std::count(std::begin(s), std::end(s), -1);
  if (outside != 1)
    return outside == 0;

  while (s[0] >= 0)
  {
    std::rotate(std::begin(t), std::begin(t) + 1, std::end(t));
    std::rotate(std::begin(s), std::begin(s) + 1, std::end(s));
  }

  double 
    min_org = std::min({
      ncos(t[0], t[1], t[2]), ncos(t[2], t[0], t[1]), 
      ncos(t[1], t[0], p), ncos(p, t[1], t[0]) }),
    min_alt = std::min({
      ncos(t[1], t[2], p), ncos(p, t[2], t[0]), 
      ncos(t[0], p, t[2]), ncos(t[2], p, t[1]) });

  return min_org <= min_alt;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding how this works.

How do "sum of angles" and "minimum of all cosines" relate? Cosines of certain angles are always negative, and I would think you could position your triangle to arbitrarily fall within that negative range. So how is this test valid?

Additionally, after collecting the two sets of "minimum cosines" (rather than the two sets of angle sums), the final test is to see which minimum is smallest. Again, I don't see how this relates to the original test of determining whether a triangle is valid by using the flip condition.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that there is a well-known function for finding out if a Point D lies within the circumcircle of triangle ABC by computing the determinant shown below.  If InCircle comes back greater than zero, then D lies within the circumcircle and a flip is required.  The equation does assume that the triangle ABC is given in counterclockwise order (and, so, has a positive area).

[image]

I got this equation from the book Cheng, et al. "Delaunay Mesh Generation" (2013), but you should be able to find it in other places.  An open-source Java implementation is available at https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour, but I'm sure you can find examples elsewhere, some of which may be better suited to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the method I currently use, which works great for "reasonably" sized triangles. For my case, I'm attempting to perform this operation on truly massive triangles (points are millions of units apart), and the math involved for calculating the determinant is overflowing even 64-bit variables. I've also tried using floating point and scaling down the numeric range for this comparison, but the edge cases where the point is near the circle edge are breaking things. I'm trying to find an exact method that can handle the higher integer range.